# Software for creating simple X,Y graphs

Tags: graphing-functions, math-software

I need to be able to plot X,Y graphs as well circles. I tried using octave but the functionality is just not there.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

I want to be able to generate graphs that are like this:

[image]

Comment: You could use the free online [Desmos Graphing Calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out **[geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org)**: it's *free* open source software, readily available for download.!

You can draw with or without a pre-formatted coordinate grid with $x, y$ axes, and can draw shapes of any sort. The learning curve is not at all steep, so you can be up and running shortly after downloading!

Comment: You're welcome! There is also [free geogebra applications](http://www.geogebra.org/cms/download) for tablets.

Comment: this is a 404 link

Comment: solved @Kansai !